# What is the best way to run my program every morning and email report?

Tags: java, automation, report

I currently have a java program that analyses data and outputs a report to the console. I run this every morning, as the data is pulled from a webpage which changes daily.

What is the best way for me to automate this program and get it to run every morning and maybe email the report to me? Is there some way of uploading it online?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Rob

Comment: Implement a cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) was made for.

> Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems.

Here is a related question that talks about Java and cron:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98914/how-to-use-crontab-for-a-java-file-in-linux

Comment: Thank you, looks like it could do the job!